# automatically install jdk when you install the server application in rpmbuild

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild, rhel7

I'm trying to do my rpm containing configured server wildfly together with the application. I'm trying to make RPM contains the JDK. The file below is only an indication of the required element. Is it possible to do so during the installation wildfly-as-8.0.0-0.1.Beta1.el7.noarch.rpm automatically install JDK (jdk-8u92-linux-x64.rpm). So that you can install a whole, even without Internet access.

```
%global namedreltag .Beta1
%global namedversion %{version}%{?namedreltag}

# We don't need to repack jars for this package
%define __jar_repack %{nil}
# There are some arch dependent files, ignore them
%define _binaries_in_noarch_packages_terminate_build 0

Name:             wildfly-as
Version:        8.0.0
Release:        0.1%{namedreltag}%{?dist}
Summary:        WildFly Application Server

License:        LGPLv2+ and ASL 2.0 and GPLv2 with exceptions
URL:              http://wildfly.org/
Source0:        http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/%{namedversion}/wildfly-%{namedversion}.tar.gz

Requires:       jdk >= 1:1.8

BuildArch:     noarch

%description
WildFly Application Server (formerly known as JBoss Application Server) is the
latest release in a series of WildFly offerings. WildFly Application Server, is
a fast, powerful, implementation of the Java Enterprise Edition 6
specification.  The state-of-the-art architecture built on the Modular Service
Container enables services on-demand when your application requires them.

Please note that this package is not following the Fedora guidelines. This
package is created to make the OpenShift cartridge for WildFly.

%prep
%setup -q -n wildfly-%{namedversion}

%install
install -d -m 755 %{buildroot}/opt/wildfly-%{namedversion}

cp -r * %{buildroot}/opt/wildfly-%{namedversion}

%files
/opt/wildfly-%{namedversion}
%doc README.txt README.txt

%changelog
* Thu Dec 05 2013 Marek Goldmann <mgoldman@redhat.com> - 8.0.0-0.1.Beta1
- Initial packaging
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rpmbuild simply runs scripts, any procedure you can script can be performed during a build, including downloading/installing/removing a jdk.

Meanwhile, what is usually done is to add Buildrequires: to your package that specify what is needed, and then let a dependency solver like yum/dnf do the installation, rather than having every package build trying to do custom installations of prerequisites.